# git windows post pull

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, hook, pull

I have recently converted from svn.
My server is under Windows (don't blame me, it wasn't my choice :}

I have created a repo with two branches "master" and "stable".

On my server I want to get files from stable branch.

I have done:

```
git clone git://url/.git src
cd src
git checkout --track -b stable origin/stable
```

Previously I had a .bat script

```
cd my_repo_dir
svn update
echo APPLICATION_STAGE = 'production' > conf\__init__.py
net stop apache2.2
net start apache2.2
```

and it worked, now with git

```
cd my_repo_dir
git pull
echo APPLICATION_STAGE = 'production' > conf\__init__.py
net stop apache2.2
net start apache2.2
```

nothing is executing after git pull, whether it is successful, or up-to-date.
It just exits to prompt with no warning.

I thought about hooks.
I have created:

```
.git/hooks/post-receive
.git/hooks/post-update
```

both files with the same contents:

```
echo APPLICATION_STAGE = 'production' > conf\__init__.py
net stop apache2.2
net start apache2.2
```

and nope, it is not executing either...
Maybe I am missing interpreted declaration line (#!/bin/sh on *nix)
but I am not sure what it is on windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few points:

- Make sure you have git.exe on path. Do a `where git` and you must get something like

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
  ```

  If git.cmd is being used ( from C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.cmd ), you have to do `call git pull` for it to continue execution. I would say add `git.exe` to path and start using it.
- Even on Windows, you must have the shebang - `#!/bin/sh` for the hooks to properly run.
- If you want a hook to run on pull, you probably want to use the `post-merge` hook. `post-receive` and `post-update` run on remote repos when you push to them.

Answer (score 1):

`git` is probably a batch wrapper around the real executable. Use `call git pull`.

And those hooks only fire when content is pushed from a remote location, as far as I can tell from the documentation. So they're ignored for `pull`.