# How to automatically run another application after pull on repository?

Tags: git, push, githooks, pull

I have 2 Git repository. After push in my main repository automatically pulling another (by hook). What **command** can help me run external application for doing additional work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`post-merge` hook](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_merge) should run after a `git pull`.

Make sure to avoid the issues mentioned in "[git windows post pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286982/git-windows-post-pull)" or "[git hook post-merge - error: cannot run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563904/git-hook-post-merge-error-cannot-run)".

You have an example of "additional work" in "[Git `post-merge` hook to auto-fire rails migrations](http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2010/02/27/git-post-merge-hook-to-auto-fire-rails-migrations/)"

Comment: @dsm you mean you don't know how to define a post-merge hook? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563904/git-hook-post-merge-error-cannot-run illustrates that.

Comment: need run c:\ttt.exe. What need write on hook body?

Comment: @dsm: just `#!/bin/sh` followed by `/c/ttt.exe`: unix-style. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286982/git-windows-post-pull